# How are statically allocated arrays laid out in memory in C?

Tags: c, local-variables, memory-layout

I was playing around with pointers trying to manipulate the value of one var using the pointer to another var, based on how the local vars are typically stacked in a C program.

```c
int i = 30;
int arr[4];

printf("%d\n", *(arr - 5)); // 30
```

```c
int arr[4];
int i = 30;

printf("%d\n", *(arr - 5)); // also 30
```

I thought that the latter should print 30 for `*(arr + 5)`, because that's how I thought the local vars are pushed onto the stack, but the vars seemed to be laid out in memory in the same manner. I'd like to understand what's happening here. Also, I'm assuming this is system/compiler dependent.

Comment: You are playing with an *undefined behavior* here. So your finding are not necessarily have much of meaning.

Comment: How the things are stored in memory is indeed mostly compiler/platform specific.

Comment: The compiler can arrange variables as he wants, he does not need to arrange them in the same order than the declaration. They don't even need to be adjacent in memory (but most of the time the are) and ther may be padding between them.

Comment: Thanks! Clears my doubt. I was wondering if the compiler does actually change the order of pushes.

Comment: You can eperience this kind of things here: https://www.godbolt.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: Memory layout (between different variables) is up to the compiler, and is implementation dependent.

Long Answer: The compiler can decide how to allocate memory to variables. While most compilers will allocate the memory sequentially, there is no guarantee. In particular, especially when optimizing, the compiler may be able to eliminate unused variables, or just placed them into registers.

Another factor is alignment. The compiler may decide to reorder variables to reduce the padding between variables.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing values beyond array bounds has undefined effects.  In your case, the value you are getting is random and it just happens to be 30.

Comment: I can assure you it's not random, but as many others pointed out, it's clear that the compiler may not follow the order that the programmer declared the variables in.

Comment: I got '0' for the same code fragment above.  So 30 just happens to be the value at the location being accessed.

Comment: Which does not mean it is random. I am pretty sure that the OP will get 30 *consistently* across multiple runs.

Comment: It's not random, it's at best undetermined.

Comment: @Ranganatha You could try `*(arr + 5)` or `*(arr + 4)` and see if you can access the value of `i`.